# Dart Force enum values in switch outside of enum class

Tags: flutter, dart, enums, switch-statement

I'd like to use dart enums for more flow control outside of the enum class and allow the compiler to catch any missing enum cases in that switch.

I'm coming from Swift where enums can be defined and then later using the enum value coming in for force compiler flow control. So when developers add a new enum, they can update each location with the specific code flow.

I don't see any easy option to allow this type of programming.

This example is using MQTT topics with subscribes and I'd like to add code in all code locations where the enum is used.

```
enum SubscribeTopicType {
  configData,
  statusSensors,
}
```

So example above, I added "statusSensors" to the enum.

Inside the enum with an extension, the compiler catches any missing new enum types added.

```
extension SubscribeTopicTypeExtension on SubscribeTopicType {



  String get endpointValue {
    switch (this) {
      case SubscribeTopicType.configData:       return "data/configurationData/";
      case SubscribeTopicType.statusSensors:    return "data/sensorData/";
    }
  }
```

But when using the enum outside of the enum class or extension, the compiler doesn't find the missing case.

MqttManager class:

```
  void _processSubscribePayload(SubscribeTopicType subscribeTopicType, String payload) {

    switch (subscribeTopicType) {
      case SubscribeTopicType.configData:
        _subscribeConfigData(payload);
        break;


      // the code commented out will stop the compiler from requiring the new enum value.
      // case SubscribeTopicType.statusSensors:
      //  _subscribeStatusSensors(payload);
      //  break;
    }
  }
```

Is this a gap or missing feature in dart?  Or is there a way to force code flow control with enums?

Comment: I've been away from dart/flutter for a while, but you shouldn't be able to do that. You might consider to use freezed's unions instead (https://pub.dev/packages/freezed#unionssealed-classes), which can be used to emulate kotlin's sealed classes and "when" operator

Comment: How is the `endpointValue` extension method relevant?  [Using an `enum` in a `switch` normally does generate an analysis warning](https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages#missing_enum_constant_in_switch).

Comment: `dart analyze` generates a warning about the missing case for me; I can't reproduce your problem. [DartPad also shows a warning](https://dartpad.dev/?id=3438565ca1891680b66321b8ae192355&null_safety=true).

Comment: @jamesdlin interesting. I'm using Android Studio and it does highlight the switch statement but the app doesn't fail compilation. `Missing case clause for 'statusSensors'. (Documentation)` maybe I can force the compiler to stop on that, but AS does launch the app.  new guy in Dart so I'm figuring things out. thanks.

Comment: It will generate an analysis warning, not a compilation error.

Comment: @GiovanniLondero that's a good idea.  thank you. I've use when a bit in Kotlin before.  That might just work as a solution as well. I may see if I can put a pre processor check style type verification to ensure all cases are met. Although, I'm not sure if there's some type of check style option for that. too bad you can't pass a compiler setting to just force all usages to meet all options like Swift does. I suspect Kotlin might have the same option?  thanks again.